# triggering intermediary transition between states in ruby state_machine

Tags: ruby, state-machine, transition

i am using https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine

my code is

```
event :set_running do
 transition any => :runnning
end

event :restart do
 transition :failed => :restarting
end

after_transition :failed => :restarting do |job,transition|
  job.set_running
end

after_transition :restarting => :running do |job,transition|
  job.restart_servers 
=begin 
 this takes some time. and i would like job state to be "restarting" while
 it's restarting servers. but it doesn't happen (i suppose because of transaction) 
 until after_transition :failed => :restarting callback is finished.
 so it actually doesnt happen at all because this callback triggers => :running transition
=end
end
```

in other words i would like to run "restart" event once and trigger intermediary transition while it's transferring from :failed to :running.
can i do that somehow using state_machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://rdoc.info/github/pluginaweek/state_machine/master/StateMachine/Integrations/ActiveRecord

It is now possible to disable transactions:

```
state_machine :initial => :parked, :use_transactions => false do
```